# sqlite3 bus error

Tags: c, macos, cocoa, sqlite, bus-error

I'm writing an app that uses sqlite3. For some very bizarre reason, it crashes only on some machines. I was unable to reproduce the error, but a couple beta testers are reporting it. When the app is opened it automatically quits. It says it crashed because of a bus error. I tried everything, but I was unable to solve the problem. The app works fine on my 3 Macs(one running Tiger, another running Snow Leopard and the other one running Mountain Lion). Considering the crash log, the problem happens on this method:

```
+(BOOL)hasAnyBlog{
    int rc;

    sqlite3 *database = NULL;

    rc = sqlite3_open([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Library/Application Support/metropolis/database.db", NSHomeDirectory()] UTF8String], &database);

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"SELECT URL, username, password, token, type, name, id FROM blogs ORDER BY name ASC"];

    sqlite3_prepare(database, [str UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL);

    NSMutableArray *array = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

    if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW){
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(database);
        return NO;
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(database);
    return YES;
}
```

Does anyone know what could be causing it? Here's the crash log:

```
Process:         Metropolis [17035]
Path:            /Applications/Metropolis.app/Contents/MacOS/Metropolis
Identifier:      com.chiaro.metropolis
Version:         ??? (1.6)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [79]

Date/Time:       2013-04-07 15:00:08.566 +0200
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          164186 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           2
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  6 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   1
Anonymous UUID:                      161026F3-C64B-4813-90DC-64A94B9E4770

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000000001
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x98091225 sqlite3_step + 37
1   com.chiaro.metropolis             0x00012bc7 0x1000 + 72647
2   com.chiaro.metropolis             0x00031c0d 0x1000 + 199693
3   com.apple.AppKit                  0x93c9fd59 -[NSTableView numberOfRows] + 142
4   com.apple.AppKit                  0x93be92c0 -[NSTableView _totalHeightOfTableView] + 42
5   com.apple.AppKit                  0x93be9275 -[NSTableView _minimumFrameSize] + 72
6   com.apple.AppKit                  0x93be8c0b -[NSScrollView tile] + 1295
7   com.apple.AppKit                  0x93be86ed -[NSScrollView _tileWithoutRecursing] + 46
8   com.apple.AppKit                  0x93b82b79 -[NSScrollView reflectScrolledClipView:] + 285
9   com.apple.AppKit                  0x93bf4615 -[NSClipView _reflectDocumentViewFrameChange] + 122
10  com.apple.AppKit                  0x93b3f713 -[NSView _postFrameChangeNotification] + 135
11  com.apple.AppKit                  0x93b398e6 -[NSView setFrameSize:] + 809
12  com.apple.AppKit                  0x93b63e5a -[NSControl setFrameSize:] + 128
13  com.apple.AppKit                  0x93bf41b0 -[NSTableView setFrameSize:] + 230
14  com.apple.AppKit                  0x93bf05d6 -[NSTableView _tileAndRedisplayAll] + 177
15  com.apple.AppKit                  0x93ca0f0e -[NSTableView setDataSource:] + 279
16  com.apple.AppKit                  0x93b1e903 -[NSNibOutletConnector establishConnection] + 406
17  com.apple.AppKit                  0x93b1d08f -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 1249
18  com.apple.AppKit                  0x93b1b1a4 loadNib + 257
19  com.apple.AppKit                  0x93b1a7f7 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 831
20  com.apple.AppKit                  0x93b1a4ad +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibFile:externalNameTable:withZone:] + 158
21  com.apple.AppKit                  0x93b1a3f8 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 383
22  com.apple.AppKit                  0x93b171fd NSApplicationMain + 434
23  com.chiaro.metropolis             0x00002bbe 0x1000 + 7102
24  com.chiaro.metropolis             0x00002ae5 0x1000 + 6885

Thread 1:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x9049f382 kevent + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x9049fa9c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 215
2   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x9049ef59 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 163
3   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x9049ecfe _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 240
4   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x9049e781 _pthread_wqthread + 390
5   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x9049e5c6 start_wqthread + 30

Thread 2:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.CFURLCACHE_work_queue
0   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x904adb26 fsync$UNIX2003 + 10
1   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x98000f3c unixSync + 76
2   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x9800404c syncJournal + 396
3   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x98019019 sqlite3PagerCommitPhaseOne + 1337
4   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x980198af sqlite3BtreeCommitPhaseOne + 607
5   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x9804e962 sqlite3VdbeHalt + 3394
6   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x98087de8 sqlite3VdbeExec + 12184
7   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x98091867 sqlite3_step + 1639
8   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x98092378 sqlite3_exec + 312
9   com.apple.CFNetwork               0x9362c2e2 __CFURLCache::PostDatabaseOpenPragmaExecute() + 80
10  com.apple.CFNetwork               0x9362bfd5 __CFURLCache::OpenDatabase() + 173
11  com.apple.CFNetwork               0x9362b9fb ProcessCacheTasks(__CFURLCache*) + 629
12  com.apple.CFNetwork               0x9362b226 _CFURLCacheTimerCallback(void*) + 403
13  libSystem.B.dylib                 0x904aca24 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 16
14  libSystem.B.dylib                 0x9049f48c _dispatch_queue_drain + 249
15  libSystem.B.dylib                 0x9049eee8 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 50
16  libSystem.B.dylib                 0x9049ecfe _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 240
17  libSystem.B.dylib                 0x9049e781 _pthread_wqthread + 390
18  libSystem.B.dylib                 0x9049e5c6 start_wqthread + 30

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x9049e412 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x9049e9a8 _pthread_wqthread + 941
2   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x9049e5c6 start_wqthread + 30

Thread 4:  WebCore: LocalStorage
0   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x904a6aa2 __semwait_signal + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x904a675e _pthread_cond_wait + 1191
2   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x904a83f8 pthread_cond_wait$UNIX2003 + 73
3   com.apple.JavaScriptCore          0x90b96fd1 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 81
4   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x904a6259 _pthread_start + 345
5   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x904a60de thread_start + 34

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x90478afa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x90479267 mach_msg + 68
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x909492df __CFRunLoopRun + 2079
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x909483c4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x909481f1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
5   com.apple.Foundation              0x95238224 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 329
6   com.apple.Foundation              0x951ff4c4 -[NSThread main] + 45
7   com.apple.Foundation              0x951ff474 __NSThread__main__ + 1499
8   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x904a6259 _pthread_start + 345
9   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x904a60de thread_start + 34

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
 eax: 0x00000001  ebx: 0x98091211  ecx: 0x94b8f7e2  edx: 0x01037800
 edi: 0x00000001  esi: 0x00000015  ebp: 0xbffff2c8  esp: 0xbffff150
  ss: 0x0000001f  efl: 0x00010202  eip: 0x98091225   cs: 0x00000017
  ds: 0x0000001f   es: 0x0000001f   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x00000037
 cr2: 0x00000001

Binary Images:
   0x1000 -    0x64fff +com.chiaro.metropolis ??? (1.6) <BCA38D82-D970-49AE-BD18-3773687C584F> /Applications/Metropolis.app/Contents/MacOS/Metropolis
  0x7f000 -    0x8706f +net.liquidx.EyeTunes ??? (1.2) /Applications/Metropolis.app/Contents/Frameworks/EyeTunes.framework/Versions/A/EyeTunes
  0x90000 -    0xb6fff  libssl.0.9.7.dylib 0.9.7 (compatibility 0.9.7) <9203FADE-F4F2-2245-A32E-BD88819D314D> /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.7.dylib
  0xc5000 -   0x17afe7  libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib 0.9.7 (compatibility 0.9.7) <AACC86C0-86B4-B1A7-003F-2A0AF68973A2> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib
 0x1c0000 -   0x1d3ff7 +org.andymatuschak.Sparkle 1.5 Beta (bzr) (1.5) <B71AAB2E-CF96-C369-8F24-05DA34F5B92D> /Applications/Metropolis.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Sparkle
0x8fe00000 - 0x8fe4163b  dyld 132.1 (???) <4CDE4F04-0DD6-224E-ACE5-3C06E169A801> /usr/lib/dyld
0x90003000 - 0x90017ffb  com.apple.speech.synthesis.framework 3.10.35 (3.10.35) <57DD5458-4F24-DA7D-0927-C3321A65D743> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesis
0x90018000 - 0x90068ff7  com.apple.framework.familycontrols 2.0.2 (2020) <596ADD85-79F5-A613-537B-F83B6E19013C> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyControls.framework/Versions/A/FamilyControls
0x90122000 - 0x901a2feb  com.apple.SearchKit 1.3.0 (1.3.0) <9E18AEA5-F4B4-8BE5-EEA9-818FC4F46FD9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
0x901a3000 - 0x902a3fe7  libxml2.2.dylib 10.3.0 (compatibility 10.0.0) <BE7FCD73-03B5-25A4-FCA4-D4980F1488D6> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x902a4000 - 0x902a9ff7  com.apple.OpenDirectory 10.6 (10.6) <0603680A-A002-D294-DE83-0D028C6BE884> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/OpenDirectory
0x902ac000 - 0x902bafe7  libz.1.dylib 1.2.3 (compatibility 1.0.0) <33C1B260-ED05-945D-FC33-EF56EC791E2E> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x902c0000 - 0x902d1ff7  com.apple.LangAnalysis 1.6.6 (1.6.6) <3036AD83-4F1D-1028-54EE-54165E562650> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LangAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/LangAnalysis
0x90449000 - 0x9046fffb  com.apple.DictionaryServices 1.1.2 (1.1.2) <43E1D565-6E01-3681-F2E5-72AE4C3A097A> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
0x90478000 - 0x9061fff7  libSystem.B.dylib 125.2.11 (compatibility 1.0.0) <2DCD13E3-1BD1-6F25-119A-3863A3848B90> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x90620000 - 0x90673ff7  com.apple.HIServices 1.8.3 (???) <1D3C4587-6318-C339-BD0F-1988F246BE2E> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices
0x906ef000 - 0x908b2feb  com.apple.ImageIO.framework 3.0.6 (3.0.6) <AE641FAD-DF38-AE31-B45B-85AEE7AF3A45> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
0x9090c000 - 0x90a87fe7  com.apple.CoreFoundation 6.6.6 (550.44) <F88C95CD-1264-782D-A1F5-204739847E93> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
0x90a88000 - 0x90b1afe7  com.apple.print.framework.PrintCore 6.3 (312.7) <7410D1B2-655D-68DA-D4B9-2C65747B6817> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PrintCore.framework/Versions/A/PrintCore
0x90b63000 - 0x90b69fe7  com.apple.CommerceCore 1.0 (9.1) <521D067B-3BDA-D04E-E1FA-CFA526C87EB5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommerceCore.framework/Versions/A/CommerceCore
0x90b8c000 - 0x90e3afe7  com.apple.JavaScriptCore 6534.58 (6534.58.1) <8A25C759-F46B-D303-23D3-22BBFBDEEBDE> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/A/JavaScriptCore
0x90e54000 - 0x90ecefff  com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 3.2.6 (3.2.6) <156A532C-0B60-55B0-EE27-D02B82AA6217> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio
0x90f4d000 - 0x90f6cff7  com.apple.CoreVideo 1.6.2 (45.6) <EB53CAA4-5EE2-C356-A954-5775F7DDD493> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
0x90f6d000 - 0x90fa0fff  libTrueTypeScaler.dylib ??? (???) <8ADB7D19-413E-4499-C874-13C383F97685> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTrueTypeScaler.dylib
0x90fa6000 - 0x91054ff3  com.apple.ink.framework 1.3.3 (107) <233A981E-A2F9-56FB-8BDE-C2DEC3F20784> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Versions/A/Ink
0x9105e000 - 0x9108fff7  libGLImage.dylib ??? (???) <D18E2E76-DBF4-6930-039A-F66CA0D120B3> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLImage.dylib
0x9112f000 - 0x91545ff7  libBLAS.dylib 219.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <C4FB303A-DB4D-F9E8-181C-129585E59603> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
0x91546000 - 0x9155bfff  com.apple.ImageCapture 6.1 (6.1) <B909459A-EAC9-A7C8-F2A9-CD757CDB59E8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageCapture.framework/Versions/A/ImageCapture
0x9155c000 - 0x91560ff7  IOSurface ??? (???) <89D859B7-A26A-A5AB-8401-FC1E01AC7A60> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface
0x91be5000 - 0x91c06fe7  com.apple.opencl 12.3.6 (12.3.6) <B4104B80-1CB3-191C-AFD3-697843C6BCFF> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL
0x91d2a000 - 0x92519557  com.apple.CoreGraphics 1.545.0 (???) <1D9DC7A5-228B-42CB-7018-66F42C3A9BB3> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
0x92582000 - 0x92584ff7  libRadiance.dylib ??? (???) <090420B3-CB65-9F7B-5349-D42F2F9693B6> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRadiance.dylib
0x92585000 - 0x92620fe7  com.apple.ApplicationServices.ATS 275.19 (???) <2E83B3E9-AF39-36FC-5D05-CC1E952098AB> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/ATS
0x92621000 - 0x92624ffb  com.apple.help 1.3.2 (41.1) <8AC20B01-4A3B-94BA-D8AF-E39034B97D8C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Help.framework/Versions/A/Help
0x92625000 - 0x92694ff7  libvMisc.dylib 268.0.1 (compatibility 1.0.0) <595A5539-9F54-63E6-7AAC-C04E1574B050> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
0x92695000 - 0x926a0ff7  libGL.dylib ??? (???) <3E34468F-E9A7-8EFB-FF66-5204BD5B4E21> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib
0x9271b000 - 0x92a3ffef  com.apple.HIToolbox 1.6.5 (???) <21164164-41CE-61DE-C567-32E89755CB34> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
0x92a40000 - 0x92a43fe7  libmathCommon.A.dylib 315.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <1622A54F-1A98-2CBE-B6A4-2122981A500E> /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
0x92a44000 - 0x92a54ff7  libsasl2.2.dylib 3.15.0 (compatibility 3.0.0) <C8744EA3-0AB7-CD03-E639-C4F2B910BE5D> /usr/lib/libsasl2.2.dylib
0x92a55000 - 0x92cbbff7  com.apple.security 6.1.2 (55002) <3FA54D69-5476-78DD-0AFC-D6697263890E> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
0x92d92000 - 0x931c7ff7  libLAPACK.dylib 219.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <5E2D2283-57DE-9A49-1DB0-CD027FEFA6C2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
0x93626000 - 0x93626ff7  com.apple.CoreServices 44 (44) <51CFA89A-33DB-90ED-26A8-67D461718A4A> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
0x93627000 - 0x936d3fe7  com.apple.CFNetwork 454.12.4 (454.12.4) <DEDCD006-389F-967F-3405-EDF541F406D7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
0x936d4000 - 0x936d4ff7  com.apple.Carbon 150 (152) <8F767518-AD3C-5CA0-7613-674CD2B509C4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon
0x93893000 - 0x938e0feb  com.apple.DirectoryService.PasswordServerFramework 6.1 (6.1) <00A1A83B-0E7D-D0F4-A643-8C5675C2BB21> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PasswordServer.framework/Versions/A/PasswordServer
0x938eb000 - 0x938ebff7  com.apple.Accelerate 1.6 (Accelerate 1.6) <3891A689-4F38-FACD-38B2-4BF937DE30CF> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
0x93b15000 - 0x943f8ff7  com.apple.AppKit 6.6.8 (1038.36) <A353465E-CFC9-CB75-949D-786F6F7732F6> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
0x94458000 - 0x9445efff  com.apple.CommonPanels 1.2.4 (91) <2438AF5D-067B-B9FD-1248-2C9987F360BA> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommonPanels.framework/Versions/A/CommonPanels
0x9458d000 - 0x94590ff7  libCoreVMClient.dylib ??? (???) <37F56237-4ABA-E5B5-968D-70FFE357E8E0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x94591000 - 0x945cbff7  libcups.2.dylib 2.8.0 (compatibility 2.0.0) <A6C207E3-7B42-926D-9C93-BE3F50B92496> /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
0x945cc000 - 0x9461cfe7  libTIFF.dylib ??? (???) <AB182CEC-188A-F2BC-21E1-0059FD3B2598> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
0x9461d000 - 0x9467aff7  com.apple.framework.IOKit 2.0 (???) <3DABAB9C-4949-F441-B077-0498F8E47A35> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x9467b000 - 0x94686ff7  libCSync.A.dylib 545.0.0 (compatibility 64.0.0) <287DECA3-7821-32B6-724D-AE03A9A350F9> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCSync.A.dylib
0x946d9000 - 0x946e3fe7  com.apple.audio.SoundManager 3.9.3 (3.9.3) <5F494955-7290-2D91-DA94-44B590191771> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonSound.framework/Versions/A/CarbonSound
0x94765000 - 0x947a8ff7  com.apple.NavigationServices 3.5.4 (182) <8DC6FD4A-6C74-9C23-A4C3-715B44A8D28C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/NavigationServices.framework/Versions/A/NavigationServices
0x947c7000 - 0x948a1fff  com.apple.DesktopServices 1.5.11 (1.5.11) <800F2040-9211-81A7-B438-7712BF51DEE3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DesktopServicesPriv.framework/Versions/A/DesktopServicesPriv
0x948b2000 - 0x948f5ff7  libGLU.dylib ??? (???) <6CC3CE6A-7024-C685-EADA-7F9DC27128E2> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLU.dylib
0x948fe000 - 0x9499bfe3  com.apple.LaunchServices 362.3 (362.3) <15B47388-16C8-97DA-EEBB-1709E136169E> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
0x94a3d000 - 0x94a3dff7  com.apple.vecLib 3.6 (vecLib 3.6) <FF4DC8B6-0AB0-DEE8-ADA8-7B57645A1F36> /System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
0x94b84000 - 0x94c31fe7  libobjc.A.dylib 227.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <9F8413A6-736D-37D9-8EB3-7986D4699957> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x951e9000 - 0x9545afef  com.apple.Foundation 6.6.8 (751.63) <69B3441C-B196-F2AD-07F8-D8DD24E4CD8C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
0x9545b000 - 0x9545bff7  com.apple.Cocoa 6.6 (???) <EA27B428-5904-B00B-397A-185588698BCC> /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa
0x9554f000 - 0x959a0fef  com.apple.RawCamera.bundle 3.7.1 (570) <AF94D180-5E0F-10DF-0CB2-FD8EDB110FA2> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/Contents/MacOS/RawCamera
0x959a1000 - 0x959a3ff7  com.apple.securityhi 4.0 (36638) <6118C361-61E7-B34E-93DB-1B88108F8F18> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SecurityHI.framework/Versions/A/SecurityHI
0x95a20000 - 0x95b4efe7  com.apple.CoreData 102.1 (251) <87FE6861-F2D6-773D-ED45-345272E56463> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
0x96aa3000 - 0x96aadffb  com.apple.speech.recognition.framework 3.11.1 (3.11.1) <7486003F-8FDB-BD6C-CB34-DE45315BD82C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechRecognition.framework/Versions/A/SpeechRecognition
0x96aae000 - 0x96aafff7  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent 1.1 (1) <2D970A9B-77E8-EDC0-BEC6-7580D78B2843> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
0x96ab0000 - 0x96abcff7  libkxld.dylib ??? (???) <9A441C48-2D18-E716-5F38-CBEAE6A0BB3E> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x96abd000 - 0x96adbfe7  libPng.dylib ??? (???) <6C0B95D7-9634-E044-0B79-F1DD56961C33> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib
0x96ae7000 - 0x96b2dff7  libauto.dylib ??? (???) <29422A70-87CF-10E2-CE59-FEE1234CFAAE> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
0x96d5a000 - 0x96d67ff7  com.apple.NetFS 3.2.2 (3.2.2) <DDC9C397-C35F-8D7A-BB24-3D1B42FA5FAB> /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFS
0x96daa000 - 0x96daeff7  libGFXShared.dylib ??? (???) <09540618-2ED1-72C4-61CB-938B35927568> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGFXShared.dylib
0x96daf000 - 0x96dc7ff7  com.apple.CFOpenDirectory 10.6 (10.6) <D1CF5881-0AF7-D164-4156-9E9067B7FA37> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFOpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/CFOpenDirectory
0x97031000 - 0x97053fef  com.apple.DirectoryService.Framework 3.6 (621.15) <F38894EA-2C13-7FC5-C084-94DA0B5B6B68> /System/Library/Frameworks/DirectoryService.framework/Versions/A/DirectoryService
0x97054000 - 0x97066ff7  com.apple.MultitouchSupport.framework 207.11 (207.11) <6FF4F2D6-B8CD-AE13-56CB-17437EE5B741> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MultitouchSupport.framework/Versions/A/MultitouchSupport
0x97067000 - 0x9711ffeb  libFontParser.dylib ??? (???) <D2D0C922-5ED1-3AE9-6F99-707C74DF3E62> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontParser.dylib
0x971ba000 - 0x9733cfe7  libicucore.A.dylib 40.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <60FF302E-5FAE-749B-BC70-0496DC2FBF2D> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x9733d000 - 0x97341ff7  libGIF.dylib ??? (???) <2251F789-B187-0837-6E38-A0E5C7C4FA3C> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib
0x973f3000 - 0x97426ff7  com.apple.AE 496.5 (496.5) <BF9673D5-2419-7120-26A3-83D264C75222> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
0x9752f000 - 0x97538ff7  com.apple.DiskArbitration 2.3 (2.3) <E9C40767-DA6A-6CCB-8B00-2D5706753000> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
0x975a9000 - 0x975edff3  com.apple.coreui 2 (114) <2234855E-3BED-717F-0BFA-D1A289ECDBDA> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/CoreUI
0x975ee000 - 0x97652ffb  com.apple.htmlrendering 72 (1.1.4) <4D451A35-FAB6-1288-71F6-F24A4B6E2371> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HTMLRendering.framework/Versions/A/HTMLRendering
0x97667000 - 0x97769fe7  libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib 0.9.8 (compatibility 0.9.8) <015563C4-81E2-8C8A-82AC-31B38D904A42> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
0x9779b000 - 0x977d8ff7  com.apple.SystemConfiguration 1.10.8 (1.10.2) <50E4D49B-4F61-446F-1C21-1B2BA814713D> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
0x977d9000 - 0x977d9ff7  com.apple.ApplicationServices 38 (38) <8012B504-3D83-BFBB-DA65-065E061CFE03> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
0x977da000 - 0x97882ffb  com.apple.QD 3.36 (???) <FA2785A4-BB69-DCB4-3BA3-7C89A82CAB41> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QD.framework/Versions/A/QD
0x97883000 - 0x9791bfe7  edu.mit.Kerberos 6.5.11 (6.5.11) <F36DB665-A88B-7F5B-6244-6A2E7FFFF668> /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos
0x9791c000 - 0x97923ff3  com.apple.print.framework.Print 6.1 (237.1) <F5AAE53D-5530-9004-A9E3-2C1690C5328E> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Print.framework/Versions/A/Print
0x9792b000 - 0x979f6fef  com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices 359.2 (359.2) <7C16D9C8-6F41-5754-17F7-2659D9DD9579> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
0x97a3d000 - 0x97a40ff7  libCGXType.A.dylib 545.0.0 (compatibility 64.0.0) <4D766435-EB76-C384-0127-1D20ACD74076> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCGXType.A.dylib
0x97a41000 - 0x97a69ff7  libxslt.1.dylib 3.24.0 (compatibility 3.0.0) <E761F29A-328B-29D9-3DF0-023F2C21E500> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x97bc6000 - 0x97bdafe7  libbsm.0.dylib ??? (???) <14CB053A-7C47-96DA-E415-0906BA1B78C9> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x97d32000 - 0x97e6ffe7  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox 1.6.7 (1.6.7) <423BDE4D-5082-B6CA-BB2C-E22A037235A4> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
0x97e70000 - 0x97ed1fe7  com.apple.CoreText 151.13 (???) <23F359DA-D845-5C50-4DF3-19E858CF2B2C> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
0x97ed2000 - 0x97ffbfe7  com.apple.WebKit 6534.58 (6534.58.2) <D156AE52-5235-2C51-B522-FD3D90E474DA> /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit
0x97ffc000 - 0x980b5fe7  libsqlite3.dylib 9.6.0 (compatibility 9.0.0) <52438E77-55D1-C231-1936-76F1369518E4> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x9842f000 - 0x98473fe7  com.apple.Metadata 10.6.3 (507.15) <74F05E64-2A68-BA10-CCD4-128D164E5A0F> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
0x98474000 - 0x991ecfe7  com.apple.WebCore 6534.58 (6534.58.2) <E39A8EB5-2D9F-0459-54E1-E172689616F5> /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/WebCore.framework/Versions/A/WebCore
0x991ed000 - 0x9920dfe7  libresolv.9.dylib 41.1.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <8C2B5FA8-2469-21C7-D297-F95A0FFE5F19> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x9920e000 - 0x99249ffb  libFontRegistry.dylib ??? (???) <19ED5DE0-D3AF-B229-9193-35D58FE377E5> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontRegistry.dylib
0x9924a000 - 0x9926eff7  libJPEG.dylib ??? (???) <50E17B4D-63D6-24D3-702F-6A6E912A55EA> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib
0x9926f000 - 0x992f1ffb  SecurityFoundation ??? (???) <C4506287-1AE2-5380-675D-95B0291AA425> /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityFoundation.framework/Versions/A/SecurityFoundation
0x99327000 - 0x99407fe7  com.apple.vImage 4.1 (4.1) <D029C515-08E1-93A6-3705-DD062A3A672C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
0x9943f000 - 0x99440ff7  com.apple.audio.units.AudioUnit 1.6.7 (1.6.7) <93EC71F1-4D4E-F456-8EFE-32E7EFD7A064> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit
0x99441000 - 0x994abfe7  libstdc++.6.dylib 7.9.0 (compatibility 7.0.0) <411D87F4-B7E1-44EB-F201-F8B4F9227213> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x994ee000 - 0x994fcff7  com.apple.opengl 1.6.14 (1.6.14) <82622F67-E032-0BF6-A78D-50B346E8D0FD> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1fff  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???) <2DCD13E3-1BD1-6F25-119A-3863A3848B90> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

Comment: Are you sure that `hasAnyBlog` is called from `numberOfRows`? Anyway, you forgot to check the return values of `sqlite3_open` and `sqlite3_prepare`.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure it isn't. I thought it could be it because I added a NSLog before every method that calls sqlite. No NSLog was called. It's the first method to be called that calls something related to sqlite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there was something wrong with the built-in SQLite lib. The solution was to add the SQLite files to the project and compile SQLite as part of the project.